# After opening the keyboard in ios 12 (ionic 3), user-select: auto stops working

Tags: ios, angular, ionic-framework, ios12

I am trying to make text selectable for copy and paste in my ionic app using user-select: text. This does work fine until the keyboard is opened. After that I can no longer select the text that I could before. This only happens with the iOS 12

html:

```
<ion-header padding-top>
<ion-navbar>
<ion-title *ngIf="!isSearchbarOpened"> 
  ZipCode Lookup
 </ion-title> 
 </ion-navbar>
 </ion-header>
<ion-content>
<ion-searchbar  showCancelButton="true" [(ngModel)]="searchQuery" (search)="onSearch($event)" placeholder="Enter zipcode" animated="true" (ionCancel)="isSearchbarOpened=false"></ion-searchbar>
  <ion-row center>
    <ion-col text-center>
      <button padding ion-button (click)="getData(searchQuery)">Search</button>
      <ion-row padding>{{result.city}} {{result.state}}</ion-row> 
    </ion-col>
  </ion-row>
</ion-content>
```

css:

```
 body {
-webkit-user-select: text;  /* Chrome 49+ */
-moz-user-select: text;     /* Firefox 43+ */
-ms-user-select: text;      
user-select: text;     
}
```

Comment: Hello, would you please post code samples and output? Help us experience what you are experiencing so we can help you better.

Comment: Hello there. If I were you, I'd clarify this question by showing some of the code applicable to this issue. It's hard for us to help if we can't see what's actually going on.